# How to print specific value from foreach?

Tags: php

How can I print specific value from an array?

This is my code

```
<?php
 $custom_fields = get_custom_fields('projects');
 if(count($custom_fields) > 0){ ?>
    <?php foreach($custom_fields as $field){ ?>
       <?php $value = get_custom_field_value($project->id,$field['id'],'projects');
        if($value == ''){continue;} ?>
        <tr>
            <td class="bold"><?php echo ucfirst($field['name']); ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $value; ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php } ?>
 <?php } ?>
```

and this is my function:

```
function get_custom_field_value($rel_id, $field_id, $field_to, $format = true)
{
    $CI =& get_instance();
    $CI->db->where('relid', $rel_id);
    $CI->db->where('fieldid', $field_id);
    $CI->db->where('fieldto', $field_to);
    $row    = $CI->db->get('tblcustomfieldsvalues')->row();
    $result = '';
    if ($row) {

        $result = $row->value;
        if ($format == true) {
            $CI->db->where('id', $field_id);
            $_row = $CI->db->get('tblcustomfields')->row();
            if ($_row->type == 'date_picker') {
                $result = _d($result);
            }
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

If I `print_r(array_values($custom_fields));` I'm getting:

> Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 5 [fieldto] => projects [name] => Car Brand [slug] => projects_car_brand [required] => 1 [type] => select [options] => Abarth,Acura,Alfa Romeo,Aston Martin,Audi,Austin,Bentley,BMW,Bugatti,Buick,Cadillac,Chevrolet,Chrysler,Citroen,Corvette,Dacia,Daewoo,Daihatsu,Daimler,Dodge,Ferrari,Fiat,Ford,Honda,Hyundai,Infiniti,Isuzu,Jaguar,Jeep,Kia,Koenigsegg,Lamborghini,Lancia,Land Rover,Lexus,Lincoln,Lotus,Maserati,Maybach,Mazda,McLaren,Mercedes,MG,Mini,Mitsubishi,Morgan,Nissan,Opel,Peugeot,Pontiac,Porsche,Renault,Rolls-Royce,Rover,Saab,Scion,Seat,Skoda,Smart,SsangYong,Subaru,Suzuki,Tesla,Toyota,Vauxhall,Volkswagen,Volvo [field_order] => 0 [active] => 1 [show_on_pdf] => 0 [only_admin] => 0 [show_on_table] => 1 [show_on_client_portal] => 1 [disalow_client_to_edit] => 1 [bs_column] => 12 ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 6 [fieldto] => projects [name] => Car Model [slug] => projects_car_model [required] => 1 [type] => input [options] => [field_order] => 0 [active] => 1 [show_on_pdf] => 0 [only_admin] => 0 [show_on_table] => 1 [show_on_client_portal] => 1 [disalow_client_to_edit] => 1 [bs_column] => 12 ) )

I would like to get value stored for first array under [options] field.

Comment: Not clear as to what exactly you want.. array[0].options maybe

Comment: `echo $custom_fields[0]['options']`? I'm not sure why we need to see all the rest of the code if the value you want is in the `$custom_fields` array. Try to come up with a [mcve] for the specific task you're having problems with.

Comment: echo $custom_fields[0]['options'] will give me all the options for that field and not a value which user picked.
If I echo $value it will give me users value (typed in or picked) but from the last loop. How can I get value from first loop of foreach?